# Взять значение высоты элемента c composition api

Tags: typescript, vue3

Такой вопрос:
Какой на сегодняшний день существует - самый простой способ получить реактивное значение высоты(допустим для примера) элемента(дом  дерева), при условии что конкретные параметры у этой высоты не прописаны.
Интересует прежде всего реализация в связке с `Vue3 Composition Api`
Пробовал варианты наподобие следующего:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все они не работали.

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: На событие ресайза этот метод будет распространяться?

Comment: Не очень понял что вы имеете ввиду, но он выдаёт размеры в момент обращения, так что можете вызывать этот метод, когда вам угодно